# Declaring a Template Member Variable in a Template Class Doesn't Work in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, templates

I'm just trying to create a simple Node template class, but for some reason, the Xcode C++ compiler doesn't like T value.  The error I get is Field has incomplete type 'T'.

```
template < class T>
class Node
{
public:
    T value;
    Node<T> next;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node<T> next;
```

defines `next` as an instance of `Node`, but the latter is not yet fully defined, so the compiler doesn't know how to construct the inner `Node`. `Node` needs to be a pointer

```
Node<T>* next; // or, better, a smart pointer
```

In this way, the compiler doesn't need to "know" the full definition of `Node<T>` when encountering the line `Node<T>* next;`. It just needs to store a pointer to `Node<T>`, which, like any other pointer, is represented (on most architectures) on 4 or 8 bytes. For this reason the compiler doesn't need to know the full definition of `Node<T>`.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense!  Thank you so much! =D